Identify this spooky cartoon
I've seen a cartoon, probably on cartoon network or some other place. I've seen it in the late 90s. Country of origin: USA. I did not remember the name of the show. All I could remember the title says something like spooksville / RL Stein cartoon or something. Probably based on books.
Here are some scenes I remember:
1- A bunch of kids/teenagers joins a dinner on a table where there is a skeleton or mummy sitting on a chair next to them that scares them. Similar to texas chainsaw massacre dinner scene. In the scene where the kids sit and eat (I think they were invited), they were eating crackers or maybe long colorful rice puffs, its very similar to "Are you afraid of the dark series" but it's animated cartoon style. It could be a animated cartoon movie or something.
I remember that the intro may start as a cartoon and then transitioned into a movie where real human actors

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. Is the question actually complete? "Here are some scenes I remember: 1-" sounds as if you wanted to add more scenes you remember.

Could you be talking about Freaky Stories? I know that came out in the late 90s until 2000.

I think I found it's called The Halloween Tree (see IMDb and Wikipedia).
Watch the clip @ 21:20 mark for the scene in question:



